# SSL: Heroku, Nodejs, Socketio, ReactJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, socket.io, reactjs

I'm deploy an application to Heroku [poke-chat](https://poke-chat.herokuapp.com/), everything is fine, should be real time, but if you see the console its not working, I got this error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://poke-chat.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441366303148-19'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

And I don't know why :c

This is my index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import engine from 'socket.io';
import dbapi from './db-api';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

//Ruta de archivos estaticos

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/pokemons', (req, res) => {
    dbapi.pokemons.find((pokemons) => {
        res.json(pokemons);
    })
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

let server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`El servidor esta escuchando en el puerto ${port}`);
});

const io = engine.listen(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('message', msg);
    })
})
```

Thanks for the help :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

That's the server side code and looks fine.

The problem appears to be on the client side code, where you seem to be doing a request to

`http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441366303148-19`

#### Solution:

Change the domain to point to `https://poke-chat.herokuapp.com/` instead of `http://localhost:3000`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, glad you enjoyed it! :D